# Missing top-level build.gradle in multi-module project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm missing the "Top-Level" project build.gradle script from my project:

[image]

I imported it into Android Studio from a very complex Maven/Eclipse project, and it basically made a module ("android") in the top level of the directory, and added all the submodules ("tappurwear", "shared", etc) into that original module's directory.

I know this is a kind of messed up structure, but there's a lot of other build scripts so I can't really just move all the files into a proper separate module.

So now I'm wondering, how do I add a top-level build.gradle script, for the entire project? The usual Android Studio projects I've seen just have one, but it's treating my top-level build script as the "android" module's build script. Can I create a new build.script to be the top-level project script that shares settings with the other modules? Is there a way I can rename the top-level build script that gets used in all other module scripts, in Android Studio or Gradle?

Comment: Which project is top-level?

Comment: @ssh the "android" module is the build.script in the root level directory. Should i just rename that to something else and make a new build.gradle for the top-level?

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused about these two gradle files. I have one in my app/platforms/android and another one in my app/platforms/android/CordovaLib. Now my question is, which one is project-level and which one app-level build.gradle? Can you please help me?

Comment: Related post - [Missing project.gradle in Android View](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46230078/465053)

Comment: Related answer [Missing project.gradle in Android View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56165326/6798074)

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue on my multi-module project, this solution worked for me.

1. Closed all the open projects.
2. Removed project from recent projects in "Welcome to Android Studio" window.
3. Now click "Open existing android studio project" & browse to the project repo & select top level `build.gradle`.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have 1 or more submodules. I had this issue with one "app" submodule https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZY1x.png Your steps helped me to solve this problem

Comment: Thanks. This helped me too. However, no need to delete all projects from the recent project list. Just removing the project having issue resolved this issue

Comment: This worked, but only after doing a `git clean -dX`. *Ensure you move any `local.properties` and `keystore.properties` etc. out of the way before you do a `git clean`!*

Answer (score 3):

1. close your project
2. rename the project directory (in the workspace)
3. open the project with the new name
4. wait for gradle sync, build.gradle (project) should be added to the Gradle scripts
5. close the project
6. rename the project directory with the original name
7. reopen the project with its good name
8. wait gradle sync, the build.gradle should be here again...

Answer (score 1):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}

}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

It really doesn't matter from my experience, what you need to do is make a build.gradle file, with your favorite .txt writer (make sure it says .gradle). If your root foldere app name is say "Archiver", then you put the gradle file where you see folders like app, .idea, gradle, e.t.c.

One thing you have to keep in mind is that you may need to add a pointer to this gradle if your project can't find it for some reason.

To make sure your project looks good, go to File >> Project Structure >> Module (and every other menu you feel you implemented). If you don't see any red x's then you may be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close project.
2. Remove ".idea\project_name.iml" (name are usually same as project folder).
3. Remove reference to this file from ".idea\modules.xml".
4. Open project.

IDEA will re-create this file in projec's root folder instead of ".idea" and project-level "build.gradle" appears. This makes me think that better solution could be just moving this file outside ".idea" and correct reference in ".idea\modules.xml".

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `build.gradle` for root folder which contains `gradle.properties` and `settings.gradle` file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused about these two gradle files. I have one in my app/platforms/android and another one in my app/platforms/android/CordovaLib. Now my question is, which one is project-level and which one app-level build.gradle? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

The following steps resolved the issue for me:

1. Close project.
2. Remove ".idea\project_name.iml" (name are usually same as project folder).
3. Remove reference to this file from ".idea\modules.xml".
4. Open project in IDE