# Missing project.gradle in Android View

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

In Android Studio, project.gradle file is not show when in Android View, but is when in Project view

**Android View**
[image]

**Project View**
[image]

How can I fix this ??

Comment: Works fine in android studio 2.3.3

Comment: Related post - [Missing top-level build.gradle in multi-module project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31505263/465053)

Comment: @RBT the first answer in the above post helped me too

Answer (score 76):

From the Gradle Tool Window in Android Studio ***(View > Tool Window > Gradle)***,

1. Right click on the the project's Gradle config with ***(root)*** next to its name.
2. Click on ***Ignore Gradle project***,
3. and right click again then click on ***Unignore Gradle project***.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is a Good answer

Comment: The best answer. This should be the accepted answer. It doesn't mess the IDE with unnecessary flags or renaming project folders.

Comment: Like a charm, Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice, simple solution!

Answer (score 23):

The trigger to this 'buggy' phenomenon actually lies *outside* your project folder.

**Assuming a project name of 'SilverBirch', try this:**
(a) Close the project in Android Studio 3.0.1.
(b) Rename your project folder (inside the workspace folder) to 'SilverBitch'
(c) Re-open it via Android Studio (you obviously can't do so using 'recent projects')
(d) You should get a window titled *Import Gradle Projects* with text that reads: *The modules below are not imported from Gradle anymore. Check those to be removed from the ide project too:*
(e) Tick the (old) project name and click OK.
(f) At last your 'Android' view shows *build.gradle(Project:SilverBitch)*
(g) Repeat whole process, renaming back to original.

**Alternatively, if you're insane, do this:**
Locate the *project.dat* file AND folder for your project - it will have a path that looks something like this (assuming Windows)

```
C:\Users\<userid>\.AndroidStudio3.0\system\gradle\Projects\5be1ee38\project.dat
```

[The system-generated hex-string container name will vary, but the file is always *project.dat*]
The first line of this file references the 'missing' *build.gradle* and will clearly identify the owning project.
Delete the file AND its containing folder then re-open the project via Android Studio.

Because googling 'project.dat' yielded nothing, and because I made a rude assumption that this contained only system-generated data, and because I couldn't resist 'seeing what happens' I actually deleted 
the entire Projects file `[C:\Users\<userid>\.AndroidStudio3.0\system\gradle\Projects]`
So far, so good - no **serious** side-effects yet! Maybe those plugins needed re-specifying anyway? etc.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, good solution (others below didn't worked). Just had to close project, rename, open, wait gradle sync, close, rename again with previous name, open, and wait gradle sync, that's all...

Comment: Can't find project.dat in ubuntu

Answer (score 10):

Close Android Studio -> Remove project .idea folder -> Open Android Studio -> Open your project. This worked for me!

**NOTE**: when you remove .idea folder you will also lose project related preferences (such as XML code style for project)

Comment: The simplest and fastest way by now, and its working!

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click on "Gradle Scripts"
2. Click Load/Unload modules
3. Load unloaded project module
4. Done

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I found that my project.iml located in project/.idea
So I move it to project/
and change one line like following:

```
<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/My_Project.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/My_Project.iml" />
```

the old one should look like this:

```
<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/My_Project.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/My_Project.iml" />
```

After that, go back to android studio, every thing seems perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In your root project folder, open the `*.iml` file, and make sure that the value in `module external.linked.project.id=`, the `*.iml` filename, and the project directory name are all the same.

Now my `build.gradle (Project: X)` shows.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

- Simply go to your **AndroidStudioProjects** Directory.
- Search for your Project
- Rename it with some other name
- Strat your Android Studio, and then **Import Project (Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc.)
  mode.** let the Gradle Build Finish.

And that's it.