# How can a valid (Project) build.gradle not show in 'Android' view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio 3.0.1 *Project* window I select *Android* then expand *Gradle Scripts*

Normally the top of the list shows *build.gradle(Project:XXXX)*.

It does **not** appear,  but choosing *Project* window *Project Files* confirms it's existance.

I have laboriously compared this project's home directory to that of a 'good' project but nothing stood out.

The project was created from a recently forked repo via

```
File > New > Project from Version Control > GitHub
```

The project builds correctly, honoring my changes to the project build.gradle.

This question may have been asked [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230078) but remains unanswered,  so I am re-asking it with additional information!

Any insights or new avenues to explore would be appreciated.

**Update**
I have removed Versioning for this project and the problem persists. Have removed GitHub tag for this question.

Comment: Another related post - [Missing top-level build.gradle in multi-module project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31505263/465053)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *eventually* circumvented this bug by simply renaming the project folder!

Re-creating the problem has proved impossible, but I strongly suspect a synchronisation problem in an obscure little file called **project.dat**.

Please refer to the answer I gave to the aforementioned question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782569/2376004)!

Comment: I straightaway deleted the corresponding `project.dat` file and the problem was solved.

Comment: I don't see a project.dat

Comment: where is project.dat located?

Comment: @Mateen Chaudhry See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48782569/2376004)

Answer (score 19):

For me this worked fine.

```
      1. Close the project  using Close project option.
      2. Import the project newly from android studio.
```

Answer (score 12):

You can delete `.gradle` and `.idea` folders in your project manually and reload your project, it helped me.